# Horizontally align images inside text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div, which contains an article. I mean, it may contain text and images. Something like this:

```
Blah Blah Blah Blah    Blah Blah Blah Blah    Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah    Blah Blah Blah Blah    Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah    Blah Blah Blah Blah.
{IMAGE}
Blah Blah Blah Blah    Blah Blah Blah Blah    Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah    Blah Blah Blah Blah    Blah Blah Blah Blah.
{IMAGE}
Blah Blah Blah Blah    Blah Blah Blah Blah.
```

So, there may not be a div around every image.

But I want to horizontally align center the images with jQuery. My idea is creating a div around every image (with jQuery) with a specific class.

But I don't know how to do that in jQuery.

How to do that? **OR** Is there any better way?

**Edit:** The content is downloaded from the feed of another website. And I want to align the images center horizontally.

Comment: Are you trying to add image in div something like this :

$div = $('div');
$div.addClass('test');
$div.append('<img src="test.jpg">');

This will look like this:
<div class="test"><img src="test.jpg"/></div>

Comment: @Aby, There is already an image tag in the html. I want jQuery to detect them, and append something like `<div class="test">` before it and `</div>` after it.

Comment: +1'ed - because it's a fair question and people are unreasonable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add div around img it can be done only by css

Try This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/8fe6S/1/)

Just use `display:block` and `margin:auto`

Comment: Your solution is so simple, and it's working! Thank you very much!

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi: granted, but I answered with exactly what you were originally looking for ^^

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this :

in your case :

$('.test').append($('#image1'));

In jquery you can also use **wrap** method :
http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Ex: $('img').wrap('`<div class="test"></div>`');

Comment: you want to " create a div around every image (with jQuery) with a specific class." rite ?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery to wrap all `<img>` tags with `<div class="imageclass">`:

```
$('img').wrap('<div class="imageclass" />');
```

CSS to center the `<div>`:

```
.imageclass { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried your code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8fe6S/2/ your jQuery is working perfectly, but your css should be: `.imageclass { text-align:center; }`, I think.

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi `margin: 0 auto;` should work in the browser; jsFiddle is not exactly foolproof on CSS

Answer (score 0):

Is your html something like this?

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="column1">
        article text article text
        <img />
        article text article text
    </div>
    <div id="column2">
        article text article text
        <img />
        article text article text
    </div>
    <div id="column3">
        article text with no image
        article text with no image
        article text article text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but `<div id="columnx">` may not exist.

Comment: I think unless there is some crazy layout situation, your a lot better off doing it with CSS instead of jquery

Comment: You should include some code in your question, its really difficult to see what your trying to suggest.